# How to Write Custom logging api using log4j by extending LoggerFactory

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to write custom logger api, where i can use it in any of my programs

`MyCustLog.info("some message");`
Instead of create logger in each class of application.

The logger should be able to print logs files in different scenarios based on

1. Thread Names
2. Package name
3. Socket
4. It should print the class name from where the log lines are getting printed.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. How is this different from just using log4j? It seems that log4j offers all you are asking for. If you want the package/class name of the component that generated the log, creating a (static) logger in each class that needs to do logging will give you better performance than other ways of doing this...

Comment: The idea is to not to initiate the logger class in each class in my application and when ever a thread is created with certain name starts with specific char logs should be written in different file.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the log4j2 RoutingAppender (the FAQ page has a good example).
This appender allows you to write to different log files and even create new log files dynamically.

I still don't understand why you want to avoid creating a logger instance in the classes that need to do the logging. Making the logger instance a static field means that the logger is created only once when your class is loaded and is never garbage-collected so creating the logger will not impact performance.

Comment: The above explanation is true , but for throughout my application who ever wants to implement logging they should includent the Customlogger jar in their project and use Log.info("some msg"); no logger creation in each class.